# Cloning a 8051 flash with an Arduino

Tags: 8051

I have a 8051 microcontroller and want to copy the flash memory.

I have an Arduino, a cp2102 usb to UART module and an 8051 microcontroller. The 8051 is a zen3309AD.

How do I achieve this task. I assume I can connect the cp2102 to the 8051 and read it's flash. I read that you can do this with avr chips with avrdude but what about this one ? Is there a general software available for this ?

I also have an Arduino if I need to use a master slave setup to achieve this, in that case can someone help me with the code ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: read the datasheet for the 8051 part and implement the protocol to read the flash if internal if external then read the datasheet for the external part.

Comment: there is no reason to expect there to be avr software for this.  are you trying to use the avr as a usb to 8051 gateway for the same host software or to have the avr read it itself into the avr, or something else.

Comment: If you read the datasheet to confirm you can read/write the part using uart (cp2102 to th e8051), then just use that same protocol from the avr.

Comment: I assume you understand that using a usb uart to program an arduino is an arduino specific bootloader thing and not even an avr thing?  Each product from each vendor has its own pins and protocol for programming the flash (including the avr).  (would not assume that you can program/read an 8051 using a uart, cant program an avr that way either without a bootloader that supports it)

Answer (score 3):

If this is someone else's commercial MCU program, chances are close to 100% they set the code protection (eg. Mode 0 on this chip) and there is **no** straightforward way to extract their code. See the [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/943925/ETC/ZEN3309A/1)

> Flash存储器支持以下操作：
> (1) 代码保护控制模式编程
> ZEN3305A/08A/09A的代码保护功能为用户代码提供了高性能的安全措施。每个分区有两种模式可用。
> 代码保护模式0：允许/禁止任何编程器的写入/读取操作（不包括整体擦除）。
>
> Google translation:
> Flash memory supports the following operations:
> (1) Code protection control mode programming
> The code protection function of ZEN3305A/08A/09A provides high-performance security measures for user code. Two modes are available for each partition.
> Code protection mode 0: enable/disable any programmer's write/read operation (not including mass erase).